# Play framework in Java - errors in "hello world" example

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to start working with [play framework](https://www.playframework.com/).
I tried using the "hello world" [example](https://www.playframework.com/getting-started) for Java, but after running the "sbt run" command I get errors.
I get a lot of lines in the CMD, with the last few lines being:

```
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

and when I try to access http://localhost:9000/ I get a lot of new errors:

```
←[2K
←[11A[error] p.a.h.DefaultHttpErrorHandler -

! @7m916p156 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:254)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:148)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:302)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:224)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1307)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:542)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:496)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:390)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:521)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3962)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3985)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4946)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4952)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:592)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.initializeBinding(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @705556e6
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @705556e6
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
[error] p.a.h.DefaultHttpErrorHandler -

! @7m916p156 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:254)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:148)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:302)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:224)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1307)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:542)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:496)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:390)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:521)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3962)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3985)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4946)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4952)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:592)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.initializeBinding(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @705556e6
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @705556e6
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
```

I haven't done any changes to the original hello world example, I'm using Java 17 and sbt 1.6.1.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try to open in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.8 supports Java 8-11, I set my environmental variable "JAVA_HOME" to the Java 8 JDK and the command `sbt run` worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).